# URL decomposition using Wicket

Tags: java, url, wicket

How can I decompose a URL in Wicket? I've got the following URL:

```
http://www.example.com[:8080]/context/wicket/[bookmarkable/]WICKET-RELATED-URL
|---------------------------|-------|----------------------------------------|
              A                 B                       C
```

I found a way to get the full URL (A,B,C):

```
RequestCycle.get().getUrlRenderer().renderFullUrl(
  RequestCycle.get().getRequest().getUrl())
```

and a way to get just the context (B):

```
RequestCycle.get().getRequest().getContextPath()
```

Is there a similar way to get part (A) of the URL? Or do I have to work with substrings?

Comment: Use regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use regular expressions! ;)

There is `java.net.URL` object which parses an url and allows access to any part of it separately. Also, you could combine a new url from the parts and compose back a string form of the url.

Depends what exactly you want in wicket, maybe there is a ready to use method to do it with the wicket. You haven't told about your problem, but about a probable solution only.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. Yes, I hope there is a ready to use method, that i haven't found yet. ;-) What i have to do is: Generate a link dynamically to another web-application that is lying on the same server. I want to use this method on different servers, so try to generate ist dynamically. I have a solution, but i want to find a more "cleaner" solution.

Comment: If you generate link, I recommend you to make a special parameter for the absolute url to that another application, the hostname, port, etc from the HTTP request could be not the same as a user could hit. The http server could be hiding behind a front-end web-server or a firewall. Moreover, it makes webapps less flexible, when you could easily move them around servers. If you completely sure that web-apps are on the same container, just use a relative url as `/otherappctx/somepage.html`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use wickets `RequestUtil.toAbsolutePath(String relativePagePath)`.

According to JavaDoc, it "Calculates absolute path to url relative to another absolute url."

I've been using it with 'urlFor()' to generate links to put into mails but as long as you can define a relative path to your target, this should be your solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
RequestCycle.get().getRequest().getUrl().get(Protocol|Host|Port)()
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your advise. Calling this methods return only `null` values... :-( Because of the relative url? `String url = RequestCycle.get().getRequest().getUrl().toAbsoluteString();` The url string contains `/?0-1.ILinkListener-header-logout-logout` Any idea? Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

[Regular expressions](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html) can fit your requirements

Comment: Regular expressions will do the job! But if there is a solution by using a wicket method, i will prefer this.

Comment: Never ever use regular expressions to parse URLs. At least not in Java, there are proper library methods for this.

Comment: Regular expressions shouldn't be used when there are library methods to archive the same (and there are).

Comment: @Andrey Atapin: Well, for one, there is a `java.net.URL` class that does it for you. Duplicating built-in functionality is never a good idea. The other reason is that, no offence meant, but you'll probably get it wrong. (Not just you, I'm sure I'd get it wrong too.) The URL specification can be quite tricky at times and many home-made regex parsers I saw were not covering it fully. Of course it's fine to try it as an exercise or in a pet project but in production code, it's simpler and safer to use the built-in class.